# Error "Property 'switchmap' does not exist on type 'Observable<User | null>" when protecting admin route

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire

My admin auth serive ts is below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { UserService } from './user.service';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminAuthGaurdService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth:AuthService,private userServise:UserService) { }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.auth.user$
      .switchmap((user: { uid: String; }) => this.userServise.get(user.uid))
      .map((appUser: { isAdmin: any; })=>appUser.isAdmin);
  }
}
```

The error is "Property 'switchmap' does not exist on type 'Observable<User | null>'.ts(2339)."
I can not figure out hoe to crect this. Ihave done every thing even use pipe. and didthe all the impot that  I possibley can

Comment: From rxjs 5.0 to rxjs 6 there was breaking changes. See the [guide migration](https://v6.rxjs.dev/guide/v6/migration) -change the paths and added a pipe sintax-. NOTE: Nowadays we are in rxjs 7.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues & Concerns**

1. You need the [`.pipe()` method of `Observable` to chain the multiple operators](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-observable-pipe/#:%7E:text=The%20pipe%20method%20of%20the,it%20in%20an%20Angular%20Application.).
2. There is a typo error, should be `switchMap` but not `switchmap` for rxjs operator.
3. The `canActivate` method should be with the return type of `Observable<boolean>` as you are returning the value with the `Observable<boolean>` type.

Your code should be as below:

```
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.auth.user$.pipe(
    switchMap((user: { uid: String }) => this.userServise.get(user.uid)),
    map((appUser: { isAdmin: any }) => appUser.isAdmin)
  );
}
```